# How to kill a web process

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I have a web script that takes a really long time to run (and it's supposed to take a long time). By "web script" I mean a script that's run by visiting a page in a browser and opposed to executed on the command line. The script is in PHP and I'm on a LAMP stack.

How can I find and kill this process if I want to?

"Kill" might be the wrong word. I just want the script to stop. I could conceivably make this script "watch" for some state of my system to change, and then halt when it notices that change. If I do that, I'm not sure what the best way to do that would be. In any case, I'm completely open to any suggestions.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that you can set PHP's [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time): that is, you can specify how much time a PHP script is allowed to take before getting killed. That might be more useful than manually stopping it or trying to come up with logic to get it killed.

Comment: That is true. In this particular situation, it's important that I can kill the script at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the script starts, write its pid to a file, something like

```
 file_put_contents(getmypid ().".pid","Running");
```

And when the script is done, it deletes the file.

You then create another script that will run form cron. It looks for pid files over a certain age, and does a `kill $pid` on them

Simple.

Comment: I ended up doing this, except without the cron.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply going to the web page of the script ie.. [www.mysite.com/mywebscript.php](http://www.mysite.com/mywebscript.php) or are you running the script from another page? I'd suggest using system() or something, that way you can actually look up the process id on your linux platform.

Also, you could use a thread in your script. You could make it perform whatever, and take input at the same time, and just send a command to kill it whenever.